# Meaning of 'Pas tant de manières'

Tags: traduction

In the poem "L'Accent Grave", I came across this line:

> Suffit. Pas tant de manières. Et conjuguez-moi le verbe être, comme tout le monde...

When I looked up the meaning of 'pas tant de manières', it was translated to be 'Not so many ways', which I feel doesn't quite make sense here. Does it have a different meaning in the poem?

Link to a PDF of the poem: https://nanopdf.com/download/laccent-grave_pdf

Thank you

Comment: Beware that the pdf you posted a link to has many mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link contains *do not [put on airs](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_on_airs)* which is more insightful a translation than the word for word one you provided. The meaning of *manières* is akin to an affected *manner* (behavior) or being difficult [etc](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44988/26366). The verb [*faire*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) (see II. A. 1.) is often used with a noun to create meaningful verbal constructs about some action or its effect with a focus on *manner*, and also as a generic colloquial replacement for something more specific.